# Module parse failed in npm module

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, babeljs, npm-package

I just started learning React and NextJS and I ran into this problem when trying to install a npm package. "Module parse failed: Unexpected token (52:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file". The package I tried installing was React Baraja-JS, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-baraja-js.

Error message:

```
error - ./node_modules/react-baraja-js/src/react-baraja.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (52:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   render() {
|     return (
>       <ul id={this.props.id} className="baraja-container" ref="wrapper">
|         {this.props.children.map((Child, index) => {
|           return <li key={index}>{Child}</li>;
```

cardMenuNav.js

```
import React from 'react';
import BarajaJS from 'react-baraja-js'; // or '../dist/react-baraja-js';

const cards = [
  {
    imageSrc: 'path/to/image1.png',
    title: 'card 1',
    details: 'this is card 1'
  },
  {
    imageSrc: 'path/to/image2.png',
    title: 'card 2',
    details: 'this is card 2'
  },
  {
    imageSrc: 'path/to/image3.png',
    title: 'card 3',
    details: 'this is card 3'
  },
  {
    imageSrc: 'path/to/image4.png',
    title: 'card 4',
    details: 'this is card 4'
  },

  // add more cards ...
]

export default class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      fan: {}
    };
  }

  // Fan right
  fanEvent() {
    this.setState({
      fan: {
        direction: 'right',
        easing: 'ease-out',
        origin: {
          x: 25,
          y: 100
        },
        speed: 500,
        range: 90,
        center: true
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button id="fan-button" onClick={() => this.fanEvent()}>Fan right</button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
};
```

index.js

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import CardMenuNav from '../components/cardMenuNav';
const Home = () => {
  return ( 
    <div>
      <CardMenuNav />
    </div>
  );
}
 
export default Home;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Alcohol-Business-Website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^4.22.8",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "next": "12.2.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-baraja-js": "^1.0.7",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.23.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.5"
  }
}
```

These are the codes that I am working with. I'm not too sure what is wrong but I did some research and it said that I had a duplicate package or something is wrong with my webpack.

Comment: Please show the entire error message and stack trace.

Comment: Just uploaded the error msg but i'm not too sure about what a stack trace is, hope that helps

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue is caused by babel ignoring `node_modules`. Judging by the number of weekly downloads of the module you are trying to use (`1`), the author of the module misconfigured it. Hope somebody else knows how to fix it without involving changing the library, but for now, you can create an issue on this project's github

Comment: You could look into using [`next-transpile-modules`](https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules) to transpile the library in your Next.js app.